# My css mucks up when i add a grouped product

Tags: magento-1.9, css, grouped-products

I have a one grouped product called called hats, this has about 5 different hats in and work perfectly fine. When i make a second grouped product called shoes and add in products this then mucks up all my CSS for product list pages and also doesn't display my left-col on my search returns page. So i thought i set it up wrong, so i duplicated my hats product and just changed the name, the SKU and also the products. The same happened. So i deleted the duplicated product and tried it again this time checking the item every time i changes something. When i changed the name and SKU the CSS was fine and everything worked perfect. However when i change the items everything went wrong. I have absolutely no idea why this is happening or what is happening. Has anyone else had this problem or knows of this problem.

Sorry for being so vague but i really do not know what is going on here. if you do not like the post please don't just down vote me just write a comment and i will either try to clear it up for you or if this isn't the correct place to ask this question let me know and i will delete it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the reason was one of my products had a tiered pice and where I had edited some code, the divs weren't ending in the right place so when I have added a products without a tiered price the code was formatting was all wrong. This was fixed but simply moving one of my divs.

Comment: well done adam :D